How to fix a weird android native crash after app being launched in 2~3 secs?
My flutter app is encountering a native crash after being launched in 2~3 secs on some of android 10+ devices, without any stack traces but there are only masses of register addresses. I can't reproduce or address it by using addr2line tool according to that pc, it points to a nonsense place, unfortunately. The key tombstone files content is as follows.
Thanks a lot for your kindly help in advance.
  Flutter 3.7.8,
  compileSdkVersion 34,
  minSdkVersion 24,
  targetSdkVersion 28,
  JavaVersion.VERSION_11,
  abiFilters arm64-v8a

signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000000000000780
  x0   0000000000000000  x1   00000000b6a287de  x2   0000000000000fa0  x3   0000007e6a5c84e8
  x4   0000007eef0025f8  x5   0000007eef069340  x6   0000007bbf1730ac  x7   0000000000000000
  x8   00000000b6a287de  x9   0000000000000780  x10  00000000b6a287de  x11  0000000000000fbe
  x12  0000000000000780  x13  0000000000000066  x14  000000000000006f  x15  0000000000000072
  x16  0000007e6771d248  x17  0000007f8557302c  x18  0000007bba800000  x19  0000007bbf174000
  x20  0000000000000003  x21  0000007bbf174000  x22  0000000000000001  x23  0000007bbf173a60
  x24  0000000000000000  x25  0000000000000000  x26  0000007bbf174000  x27  0000007e676d0184
  x28  0000007bbf173a50  x29  0000007bbf1738e0  x30  0000000000000000
  sp   0000000000000000  pc   0000000000000780  pstate 0000000000001400
  v0   00000000000000000000000000000000  v1   0000000000000016000000000000004c
  v2   00000000000000000000000000000000  v3   80000000000000000000000000000000
  v4   80000000000000000000000000000000  v5   00000001000000040000000000000000
  v6   00000000000000010000000000000400  v7   80200802802008028020080280200802
  v8   00000000000000000000000500000020  v9   00000000000000000000000000000000
  v10  00000000000000000000000000000000  v11  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v12  00000000000000000000000000000000  v13  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v14  00000000000000000000000000000000  v15  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v16  40100401401004014010040140100401  v17  00010004000000008000000000000000
  v18  00000000000000000000000000000000  v19  000000000000000000000000ebad8083
  v20  000000000000000000000000ebad8084  v21  000000000000000000000000ebad8085
  v22  000000000000000000000000ebad8086  v23  000000000000000000000000ebad8087
  v24  000000000000000000000000ebad8088  v25  000000000000000000000000ebad8089
  v26  000000000000000000000000ebad808a  v27  000000000000000000000000ebad808b
  v28  000000000000000000000000ebad808c  v29  000000000000000000000000ebad808d
  v30  000000000000000000000000ebad808e  v31  0064007500740069006e00670061006d
  fpsr 00000012  fpcr 00000000
    #00 pc 0000000000000780  0000000000000780

memory near x1:
    00000000b6a287d8 ---------------- ----------------  ................

memory near x3:
    0000007e6a5c84a8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c84b8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c84c8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c84d8 0000000000000000 0000007bee67b300  ..........g.{...
    0000007e6a5c84e8 0000007ed4e71f00 0000000000000000  ....~...........
    0000007e6a5c84f8 0000000066e3fbf3 0000000000000000  ...f............
    0000007e6a5c8508 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8518 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8528 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8538 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8548 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8558 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8568 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8578 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8588 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007e6a5c8598 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x4:
    0000007eef0025b8 0000000000000005 0000007e5d33d408  ..........3]~...
    0000007eef0025c8 000000000000001a 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef0025d8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef0025e8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef0025f8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef002608 0000000000000000 0000000000000011  ................
    0000007eef002618 0000000000000000 0000000000000226  ........&.......
    0000007eef002628 0000007e629ad808 0000000000001f96  ...b~...........
    0000007eef002638 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef002648 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef002658 0000000000000000 0000007eef068e40  ........@...~...
    0000007eef002668 0000007eef06b140 0000007eef068640  @...~...@...~...
    0000007eef002678 0000000000000000 0000007eef0683c0  ............~...
    0000007eef002688 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef002698 0000007eef069440 0000007eef069540  @...~...@...~...
    0000007eef0026a8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x5:
    0000007eef069300 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff  ................
    0000007eef069310 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff  ................
    0000007eef069320 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef069330 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef069340 0000005403a06000 0000007e5d799000  .`..T.....y]~...
    0000007eef069350 0000000000003000 0000007eef069340  .0......@...~...
    0000007eef069360 0000007eef069340 0000007eef06abc0  @...~.......~...
    0000007eef069370 0000000000000000 0000007eef06b040  ........@...~...
    0000007eef069380 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff  ................
    0000007eef069390 ffffffffffffffff ffffffffffffffff  ................
    0000007eef0693a0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef0693b0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007eef0693c0 0000005003a16000 0000007e5d896000  .`..P....`.]~...
    0000007eef0693d0 0000000000009000 0000007eef0683c0  ............~...
    0000007eef0693e0 0000007eef069c40 0000007eef06a540  @...~...@...~...
    0000007eef0693f0 0000007eef06a340 0000000000000000  @...~...........

memory near x6:
    0000007bbf173068 0000007eef002638 0000007bbf173250  8&..~...P2..{...
    0000007bbf173078 0000007f854eee28 0000007eef000980  (.N.........~...
    0000007bbf173088 0000007bbf1732f0 0000007eef069340  .2..{...@...~...
    0000007bbf173098 0000007eef0025f8 0000000000000000  .%..~...........
    0000007bbf1730a8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1730b8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1730c8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1730d8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1730e8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1730f8 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173108 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173118 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173128 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173138 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173148 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173158 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x8:
    00000000b6a287d8 ---------------- ----------------  ................

memory near x10:
    00000000b6a287d8 ---------------- ----------------  ................

memory near x16:
    0000007e6771d208 0000007e676d537c 0000007e676a644c  |Smg~...Ldjg~...
    0000007e6771d218 0000007e676a24fc 0000007f8555dae0  .$jg~.....U.....
    0000007e6771d228 0000007f85518820 0000007e676a3da8   .Q......=jg~...
    0000007e6771d238 0000007e6769e9f4 0000007f8555d28c  ..ig~.....U.....
    0000007e6771d248 0000007f8557302c 0000007f8554e01c  ,0W.......T.....
    0000007e6771d258 0000007f85510b48 0000007e676a9f38  H.Q.....8.jg~...
    0000007e6771d268 0000007f8550e9b4 0000007e676b0a3c  ..P.....<.kg~...
    0000007e6771d278 0000007e676b1898 0000007e676ab6d8  ..kg~.....jg~...
    0000007e6771d288 0000007f93c94044 0000007f8551ff90  D@........Q.....
    0000007e6771d298 0000007e676df0a0 0000007e676d9600  ..mg~.....mg~...
    0000007e6771d2a8 0000007f6f787a40 0000007f85518818  @zxo......Q.....
    0000007e6771d2b8 0000007e676b4748 0000007f93c94030  HGkg~...0@......
    0000007e6771d2c8 0000007f85521a80 0000007f924b2384  ..R......#K.....
    0000007e6771d2d8 0000007e676d0a10 0000007e676de23c  ..mg~...<.mg~...
    0000007e6771d2e8 0000007e676853f8 0000007e676b1460  .Shg~...`.kg~...
    0000007e6771d2f8 0000007f8555cbd4 0000007e676bdd6c  ..U.....l.kg~...

memory near x17:
    0000007f85572fe8 d37ced08910fe129 f8686929d53bd04a  ).....|.J.;.)ih.
    0000007f85572ff8 8b080148f85f814a f940010a360000c9  J._.H......6..@.
    0000007f85573008 54000061eb09015f d65f03c0f9400500  _...a..T..@..._.
    0000007f85573018 f900051faa1f03e0 aa1f03e0d65f03c0  .........._.....
    0000007f85573028 52801028d65f03c0 6b08001f72b00008  .._.(..R...r...k
    0000007f85573038 12007808540001ac 910fe14ad00000aa  ...T.x......J...
    0000007f85573048 f8696949d37ced09 d53bd04a360000e9  ..|.Iii....6J.;.
    0000007f85573058 f85f814a2a1f03e0 a90005098b081148  ...*J._.H.......
    0000007f85573068 528002c0d65f03c0 a9bd7bfdd65f03c0  .._....R.._..{..
    0000007f85573078 a9024ff4a90157f6 2a0103f4910003fd  .W...O.........*
    0000007f85573088 94001fe5aa0003f5 b9400016aa0003f3  ..............@.
    0000007f85573098 9123a42190fff921 97fffdf0aa1503e0  !...!.#.........
    0000007f855730a8 7100091f11000408 52800060540000e2  .......q...T`..R
    0000007f855730b8 a9424ff4b9000276 a8c37bfda94157f6  v....OB..WA..{..
    0000007f855730c8 2a0003f5d65f03c0 2a1503e194002174  .._....*t!.....*
    0000007f855730d8 940023a92a1403e2 540000603100041f  ...*.#.....1`..T

memory near x18:
    0000007bba7fffc0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba7fffd0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba7fffe0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba7ffff0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800010 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800020 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800030 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800040 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800050 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800060 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800070 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800080 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba800090 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba8000a0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bba8000b0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x19:
    0000007bbf173fc0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173fd0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173fe0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173ff0 0000000000000000 0000007bbf174040  ........@@..{...
    0000007bbf174000 0000007f8549f8a8 0000007bbf173cb0  ..I......<..{...
    0000007bbf174010 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174020 0000000000000000 a73947d152282ea1  ..........(R.G9.
    0000007bbf174030 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174040 0000000000000001 0000007e5d33d400  ..........3]~...
    0000007bbf174050 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174060 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174070 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174080 0000000000000001 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174090 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1740a0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1740b0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x21:
    0000007bbf173fc0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173fd0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173fe0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173ff0 0000000000000000 0000007bbf174040  ........@@..{...
    0000007bbf174000 0000007f8549f8a8 0000007bbf173cb0  ..I......<..{...
    0000007bbf174010 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174020 0000000000000000 a73947d152282ea1  ..........(R.G9.
    0000007bbf174030 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174040 0000000000000001 0000007e5d33d400  ..........3]~...
    0000007bbf174050 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174060 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174070 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174080 0000000000000001 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174090 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1740a0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1740b0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x23:
    0000007bbf173a20 0000007e5d33d4c0 0000007bbf174000  ..3]~....@..{...
    0000007bbf173a30 0000007bbf174000 a73947d152282ea1  .@..{.....(R.G9.
    0000007bbf173a40 0000007bbf173a90 0000007f854c5cd0  .:..{....\L.....
    0000007bbf173a50 0000000000000000 0000007e676d0184  ..........mg~...
    0000007bbf173a60 ffffffffffffffff 0000007f85586388  .........cX.....
    0000007bbf173a70 0000000008000004 0000007be58870c8  .........p..{...
    0000007bbf173a80 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173a90 0000007b08000004 0000007be58870c8  ....{....p..{...
    0000007bbf173aa0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173ab0 a73947d152282ea1 0000000003452e2d  ..(R.G9.-.E.....
    0000007bbf173ac0 0000007e676f8c02 0000007e67727498  ..og~....trg~...
    0000007bbf173ad0 00000000000f4240 0000000000000000  @B..............
    0000007bbf173ae0 0000007ed4e71f00 0000007f85586388  ....~....cX.....
    0000007bbf173af0 0000007e677274a8 0000007bbf174000  .trg~....@..{...
    0000007bbf173b00 0000000000000000 0000007bbf174000  .........@..{...
    0000007bbf173b10 0000007bbf173b70 0000007e676d03c0  p;..{.....mg~...

memory near x26:
    0000007bbf173fc0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173fd0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173fe0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173ff0 0000000000000000 0000007bbf174040  ........@@..{...
    0000007bbf174000 0000007f8549f8a8 0000007bbf173cb0  ..I......<..{...
    0000007bbf174010 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174020 0000000000000000 a73947d152282ea1  ..........(R.G9.
    0000007bbf174030 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174040 0000000000000001 0000007e5d33d400  ..........3]~...
    0000007bbf174050 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174060 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174070 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174080 0000000000000001 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf174090 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1740a0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf1740b0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................

memory near x27:
    0000007e676d0140 aa1503e2aa1303e0 7100041fd63f0100  ..........?....q
    0000007e676d0150 7100081f54000140 5280039954fffba1  @..T...q...T...R
    0000007e676d0160 a942226317fffef1 aa1303e052800061  ....c"B.a..R....
    0000007e676d0170 d63f0100aa1f03e2 17fffeea2a1f03f9  ......?....*....
    0000007e676d0180 a9bf7bfd97fe6708 71002c1f910003fd  .g...{.......,.q
    0000007e676d0190 71001c1f54000060 b0000260540000a1  `..T...q...T`...
    0000007e676d01a0 97fe677bf945f000 a8c17bfdb5000060  ..E.{g..`....{..
    0000007e676d01b0 52800021d65f03c0 d101c3ff97fe63e2  .._.!..R.c......
    0000007e676d01c0 a90267faa9016ffc a90457f6a9035ff8  .o...g..._...W..
    0000007e676d01d0 a9067bfda9054ff4 f9401818910183fd  .O...{........@.
    0000007e676d01e0 aa0003f3f9400048 f9401b19aa0203f4  H.@...........@.
    0000007e676d01f0 b4000768aa0103f5 2a1f03fbf940131a  ....h.....@....*
    0000007e676d0200 91016268aa1f03f7 f90007e85280051c  ....hb.....R....
    0000007e676d0210 2a1f03e914000006 53097d3bf9400288  .......*..@.;}.S
    0000007e676d0220 54000622eb0802ff f2402effaa1703f6  ...."..T......@.
    0000007e676d0230 f9400e6854000101 f94007e0b40000c8  ...Th.@.......@.

memory near x28:
    0000007bbf173a10 00000000000f4240 0000007e40000000  @B.........@~...
    0000007bbf173a20 0000007e5d33d4c0 0000007bbf174000  ..3]~....@..{...
    0000007bbf173a30 0000007bbf174000 a73947d152282ea1  .@..{.....(R.G9.
    0000007bbf173a40 0000007bbf173a90 0000007f854c5cd0  .:..{....\L.....
    0000007bbf173a50 0000000000000000 0000007e676d0184  ..........mg~...
    0000007bbf173a60 ffffffffffffffff 0000007f85586388  .........cX.....
    0000007bbf173a70 0000000008000004 0000007be58870c8  .........p..{...
    0000007bbf173a80 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173a90 0000007b08000004 0000007be58870c8  ....{....p..{...
    0000007bbf173aa0 0000000000000000 0000000000000000  ................
    0000007bbf173ab0 a73947d152282ea1 0000000003452e2d  ..(R.G9.-.E.....
    0000007bbf173ac0 0000007e676f8c02 0000007e67727498  ..og~....trg~...
    0000007bbf173ad0 00000000000f4240 0000000000000000  @B..............
    0000007bbf173ae0 0000007ed4e71f00 0000007f85586388  ....~....cX.....
    0000007bbf173af0 0000007e677274a8 0000007bbf174000  .trg~....@..{...
    0000007bbf173b00 0000000000000000 0000007bbf174000  .........@..{...

memory near x29:
    0000007bbf1738a0 0000007bbf1738e0 0000007f9084466c  .8..{...lF......
    0000007bbf1738b0 0000007bbf1738e0 a73947d152282ea1  .8..{.....(R.G9.
    0000007bbf1738c0 0000007bbf173a50 0000007bee683fd0  P:..{....?h.{...
    0000007bbf1738d0 0000000000000003 0000007bbf174000  .........@..{...
    0000007bbf1738e0 0000007bbf173920 0000007e67682d24   9..{...$-hg~...
    0000007bbf1738f0 00000000746f6f72 00006465736f7078  root....xposed..
    0000007bbf173900 0000006164697266 a73947d152282ea1  frida.....(R.G9.
    0000007bbf173910 0000007bee67b300 0000007bbf173b20  ..g.{... ;..{...
    0000007bbf173920 0000007bbf173b10 0000007e676d014c  .;..{...L.mg~...
    0000007bbf173930 0000007bf1487c20 0000007bee67b350   |H.{...P.g.{...
    0000007bbf173940 0000020000000000 24d33428f175a0d1  ..........u.(4.$
    0000007bbf173950 0000000080001204 24c001d69618a080  ...............$
    0000007bbf173960 24d334534e6299e0 24d334534e629a80  ..bNS4.$..bNS4.$
    0000007bbf173970 24d334534e629bc0 24d334534e62e0d0  ..bNS4.$..bNS4.$
    0000007bbf173980 24d334569618a154 24d33428f175a0d0  T...V4.$..u.(4.$
    0000007bbf173990 24d33428f175a0d0 24d3345696066e24  ..u.(4.$$n..V4.$

signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 000000000000078b
  x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000007cd45ef000  x2   0000007baf5bf0f0  x3   0000000000000000
  x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000007c078361b0  x6   0000000000000001  x7   0000000000176000
  x8   00000000b6a287db  x9   000000000000078b  x10  00000000b6a287db  x11  000000000000078b
  x12  0000000000000020  x13  0000007cd56b4738  x14  0000000004000000  x15  0000000000000028
  x16  0000007cd5776490  x17  0000007cd578c5d0  x18  0000007ba4d02000  x19  000000000000005c
  x20  0000007bac1d6000  x21  0000007bac1d5cb0  x22  00000000000067df  x23  00000000000067df
  x24  0000007bac1d5cb0  x25  0000007bac1d5cb0  x26  0000007bac1d5ff8  x27  00000000000fc000
  x28  00000000000fe000  x29  0000007bac1d5c40  x30  0000000000000000
  sp   0000000000000000  pc   000000000000078b  pstate 0000000000001400
  v0   00000000000000000000000000000000  v1   00000000000000000000000000000001
  v2   00000000000000000000000000000001  v3   00000000000000000000000000000001
  v4   00000000000000000000000000000001  v5   00000000000000000000000000000001
  v6   00000000000000000000000000000001  v7   00000000000000000000000000000001
  v8   00000000000000000000000000000000  v9   00000000000000000000000000000000
  v10  00000000000000000000000000000000  v11  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v12  00000000000000000000000000000000  v13  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v14  00000000000000000000000000000000  v15  00000000000000000000000000000000
  v16  c0300c03c0300c03c0300c03c0300c03  v17  000000003000000c0000300c00000000
  v18  00000000000000000030000000000c00  v19  000000000000000000000000ebad8083
  v20  000000000000000000000000ebad8084  v21  000000000000000000000000ebad8085
  v22  000000000000000000000000ebad8086  v23  000000000000000000000000ebad8087
  v24  000000000000000000000000ebad8088  v25  000000000000000000000000ebad8089
  v26  000000000000000000000000ebad808a  v27  000000000000000000000000ebad808b
  v28  000000000000000000000000ebad808c  v29  000000000000000000000000ebad808d
  v30  000000000000000000000000ebad808e  v31  000000000000000000000000ebad808f
  fpsr 00000010  fpcr 00000000
    #00 pc 000000000000078b  000000000000078b

  and more...


use
buildTypes {
release {
debuggable true
ndk {
debugSymbolLevel 'FULL'
}
}
}

Thank you, but I can't reproduce it at all.
